# New Core Data model gives error when upgrading

Tags: ios, database, core-data, core-data-migration

I am simply wanting to add a BOOL to my core data model, but it keeps crashing my app.
I've added a new Model Version from the `Editor` menu. Added my `BOOL` then changed the `Current Model Version` to my new one.

In my App Delegate I added these options:

```
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                                   initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
    if(![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                  configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
        /*Error for store creation should be handled in here*/
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    }
```

Now when my app loads I get this error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x17e4d2a0
>   {URL=file:///var/mobile/Applications/EFB5D875-4872-4874-AF92-038C2140E9E8/Documents/Data.sqlite,
>   metadata={
>       NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 479;
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
>           Data = <92870bec c4a8794e 293dcbe9 93282d69 cb675039 cb9b9bf6 8dda6359 34697663>;
>           Event = ;
>           Snap = <97a4acac 24668ba4 a763d216 51cb1a97 9d42362f 419be977 9d2deb2e f3cd5f7e>;
>       };
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>       NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
>           ""
>       );
>       NSStoreType = SQLite;
>       NSStoreUUID = "C7D445CD-5ED7-4C36-B885-AD430911FA81";
>       "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2; }, reason=Can't find model for source store}

Doing some reading, it seems that the problem might have something to do with the fact my project has more than 1 `.xcdatamodeld` file.
I use Countly analytics, which comes with it's own `xcdatamodeld` file. It hasn't been a problem, but I think now is causing upgrade issues.

So how can I fix this to update my own core data model?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors for the store creation in your log ?

Comment: The only error I see if the one above. Then the app crashes when trying to access a core data object.

Comment: Can you try deleting out the other model and see if you still get the error ?

Comment: Are you sure you made the changes to the new version of the model and not the older version ?

Comment: I have managed to fix it using `c roald` suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940545/core-data-lightweight-migrations-and-multiple-core-data-model-files-xcdatamod I had to migrate the 2 stores into 1 first.